# Emacs Trunk: How to prevent creation of home directories in `load-path`

Tags: start-up, load-path

In the Emacs Trunk build -- i.e., built `--with-ns`, I have the following entries that get added automatically to my `load-path` when launching **without any user configuration**:

```
"." "./Applications" "./Applications (Parallels)" "./Desktop" "./Documents"
"./Downloads" "./Library" "./Movies" "./Music" "./Pictures" "./Public" "./Sites" "./Users"
```

I've done some grepping, but haven't found an option to prevent the creation of those entries.

Clearly, Emacs is scanning my home directory for all folders and creating entries based on the results.

How can I prevent the creation of those entries?

This does *NOT* happen when I launch:  **Emacs -Q**

---

**EDIT** (08/26/2015):  I have tracked down the bug and submitted a bug report -- http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21353 -- which states in relevant part:

The `default-directory` is initially set to `"."`, which results in erroneous entries being added to the `load-path` by `normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path` within `.../site-lisp/subdirs.el` when starting Emacs.  The erroneous entries look like this:

```
"." "./Applications" "./Applications (Parallels)" "./Desktop" "./Documents"
"./Downloads" "./Library" "./Movies" "./Music" "./Pictures" "./Public" "./Sites" "./Users"
```

I built Emacs Trunk from the directory `~/Desktop`, in the event that has any relevance -- `/Users/HOME/Desktop/emacs`.

Comment: According to `emacs --help`, `-Q` is equivalent to `-q --no-site-file --no-site-lisp --no-splash`. Since you say this happens without any user configuration, I'd try the `--no-site-file` and `--no-site-lisp` options individually and see which causes this behavior not to happen. I'm not sure whether or not `--debug-init` would help in this particular case, but it might.

Comment: @Trebor Rude -- I just finished tracking it down and am filling out a bug report, and will update the question to include the bug tracking number.  The problem is that the `default-directory` is set initially to `"."`, and `normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path` within `.../site-lisp/subdirs.el` adds erroneous entries to the `load-path` as a result of that `default-directory` being `"."`.

Comment: In the meantime, @lawlist, it seems that you can add `.nosearch` files to the directories that you don't want on the `load-path`, according to the documentation for `normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path`. It's possible you could also advise the function not to do anything if you don't want any of those paths on your `load-path`.

Comment: @Trebor Rude -- Other temporary workarounds include, but are not limited to:  Setting the `default-directory` manually just above `(if (fboundp 'normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path) (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))` within `.../site-lisp/subdirs.el`; or, let-binding it around; or, simply commenting out the latter (which I don't personally need for my type of setup).  And, I will programmatically delete `"."` from the `load-path` when Emacs starts up.

Comment: True, @lawlist, and while those are pretty easy workarounds to implement, they do require root access if you're on a Linux machine. It's good to have workarounds that don't require such access.